# Creating a linkages map

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have an interesting programming problem that I need to solve for a iPhone app that I am currently building. The problem is actually a logic problem that does not need to be specific to any particular programming language.

The app needs to produce a linkages map (apologies if this isn't the right terminology but it makes sense to me). You have the following data:

```
A=C
B=A
C=O
D=F
E=F
F=G
G=D
H=J
I=L
J=N
K=A
L=O
M=C
N=H
O=E
```

The letters A through to O can be linked to any other letter. The app needs to follow the links to create a map, so starting with A, A link to C, C link to O, O links to E, E links to F etc

When complete this map would look like the attached photo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEfAs.jpg

The problem I have is that I need to write code that will output any map using any combination of links. So for example another link list might look like

```
A=B
B=A
C=A
D=A
E=A
F=A
G=A
H=A
I=A
J=A
K=A
L=A
M=A
N=A
O=A
```

I can't get my head around the pseudocode / logic for drawing the app. There are always 15 letters A-O and a letter can never be linked to itself so A can never = A.

Can anyone help to come up with the logic for drawing the map?

Comment: I cannot see the direction in the image you posted. is that intended? is `A=O` the same as `O=A`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to draw a graph. There is no canonical graphical representation of a graph. So if you have no constrains how the graph should be drawn, you can simply make a row of the Letters and than draw arches between the letters according to your map,

Little like this (ASCII-ART):

1. Example

   ```
   +-----------------------------------------+
   +--------------------------------------+  |
   +-----------------------------------+  |  |
   +--------------------------------+  |  |  |
   +-----------------------------+  |  |  |  |
   +--------------------------+  |  |  |  |  |
   +-----------------------+  |  |  |  |  |  | 
   +--------------------+  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   +-----------------+  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   +--------------+  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   +-----------+  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   +--------+  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   +-----+  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   |     |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
   |  |
   +--+
   ```
2. Example

   ```
               +-----------------------------+
         +-----------------------------+     |
   +--+  +-----------------------------------+
   |  |  |     |           +--------+  |     |
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
   |     |  |  |  |  |  |     |  |  |     |  |
   +-----+  |  +--+  |  +-----+  |  +--------+
   |        +-----+  |  |     +-----------+
   |        |     +--+  +-----------------+
   |        +--------+           |
   +-----------------------------+
   ```

Look a bit confusing, but you cannot always avoid crossings. [In this example you could, but I did not try to avoid crossing, because they cannot be avoided in the general case.]